# How to run all loops for the first sample and then switch to the following samples in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a Jmeter project that contains 3 samples and one counter that is used by all three samples.
The test structure is next:

```
-Test Plan
--Thread Group
----Counter
----Listener
----Enrollment HTTP sample (SOAP request)
----Configuration HTTP sample (SOAP request)
----Start Cycle HTTP sample (SOAP request)
```

The test has a value when I run all threads and loops for the first sample, then for the second and then for the third sample.
Other words, I have to Enroll an Individual, Configure cycle and Start cycle. The counter value should be the same for all three samples.

The question is **how can I configure the test so Jmeter will execute all threads and loops for the first sample, then for the second and for the third sample separately?**

I need it into the one Jmeter project because I plan to include this test into CI process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break down your samples to different thread groups as follows:

- Thread Group 1

  - Counter
  - Enrollment
- Thread Group 2

  - Counter
  - Configuration
- Thread Group 3

  - Counter
  - Start cycle

And check `Run Thread Groups Consecutively` box on [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level. In this case thread groups will be executed one by one.

I would also recommend to take a look into [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function which returns the number of current thread, i.e. 1 for the first thread, 2 for the second, and so on. Perhaps you could switch from counter to __threadNum function. Also there is a [__counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function which is being incremented by 1 each time it's called. You may wish to check out [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series to see how you can achieve additional flexibility.